# How can I redirect automatically to an other page of my WebApp

Tags: redirect, href, jqtouch

I am currently developing a Web App under jQTouch, and I want to know how I should proceed to redirect the user *automatically* to another page of my Web App.

For instance, let's suppose I have this code :

```
 <div id="foo1">
      ...
 </div>
 <div id="foo2">
      ...
 </div>
```

Now, let's suppose that the currently visible block is `foo1`.  Which code should I write in my JavaScript file to redirect to block `foo2` (as though I clicked a link with `href="#foo2"`)?

Thanks and sorry for my English (I'm French).

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [`jQT.goTo()`](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/functions) to transfer to another page, e.g.

```
jQT.goTo('#foo2', 'slideup');
```

If you just want to trigger a click event on a link, you could use the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function in jQuery:

```
<a id="goToFoo2" href="#foo2">Go To Foo2</a>
<script>$("#goToFoo2").click()</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A standard link

```
<a href="#foo2">Link</a>
```

will not work, but you are on the right track, it just has to be in the correct setting (either a button, or a list). so either:

```
<ul class="rounded">
   <li class="arrow">
       <a href="#foo2">Link</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<a class="button" href="#foo2">Link</a>
```

will work.

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer.

In fact, what I want to do is not exactly a link, but an *automatic* redirection. For example, some websites redirect you automatically to an other page, and as for me, I want to redirect to the div of id #foo2.

Maybe I am not very clear, I am sorry if my problem is difficult to understand... But the thing is that I have found no solution to it elsewhere in the web...